Indoor elements detect from floor image
I have a large collection of floor plans that I need to convert into indoor maps by extracting walls as lines, doors as lines, and rooms as polygons. Currently, I do this process manually.
The floor plans vary in layout; some walls are represented by single lines, while others by multiple lines:

Expected Maps:

Given these variations, I believe it might be possible to automate the creation of these maps using deep learning or another suitable approach (with minimal manual adjustments if necessary).
As a newcomer to AI, I'm not sure where to begin.
Do you have any suggestions?

What's the size of dataset? How many of them are annotated?

Almost 900+ floor plan images at the moment with each almost 300-60000 square meters. Most of them are not annotated.
